# Convert a Python string without quotes to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to convert a Python string (without quotes inside the string) to a dictionary. The string has the right format, but miss the quotes in each sub-string.

Example:

```
a_string = "{Name: 2, Test: 52, Number: 150}"
```

Comment: A [JSON5](https://json5.org/) parser could do it.

Comment: yaml parser should also work.

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both.

Comment: try : `yaml.safe_load(a_string)`

Comment: How is the string defined? There are probably several solutions for the specific example string you provided. Is the key always a word consisting of letters only? And the value always a number? And the rest of the format (number of spaces, commas, etc.) exactly as in your example, or could there be variations? Different formats might require different solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is always in the exact format as your example, then the dictionary could be created with a one-liner using [dictionary comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) and some simple string methods (no imports required):

```py
a_string = "{Name: 2, Test: 52, Number: 150}"
a_dict = {key: val for key, val in [item.split(': ') for item in a_string[1:-1].split(', ')]}
```

Result:

```py
{'Name': '2', 'Test': '52', 'Number': '150'}
```

---

Or, to get integer values (not sure from your question if that's needed or not):

```py
a_dict = {key: int(val) for key, val in [item.split(': ') for item in a_string[1:-1].split(', ')]}
```

Result:

```py
{'Name': 2, 'Test': 52, 'Number': 150}
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import yaml
d = yaml.safe_load("{Name: 2, Test: 52, Number: 150}")
print(d)
# {'Name': 2, 'Test': 52, 'Number': 150}
```

Bear in mind however the possible implications of YAML syntax, eg. a `NO` in the string would be interpreted as boolean `False`.

IF you don't want to use a YAML parser, AND can be sure that the format of the string will be as shown in your example, you can also do it with only builtin functions:

```py
s = "{Name: 2, Test: 52, Number: 150}"
s1 = s[1:-1].split(", ")
d = {}
for item in s1:
  k, v = item.split(": ")
  d[k] = int(v) if v.isnumeric() else v
```

Answer (score 1):

If your actual format is really as simple as your example, it's not too hard to do:

```
>>> a_string = "{Name: 2, Test: 52, Number: 150}"
>>> cleaned = a_string.strip().lstrip('{').rstrip('}')
>>> cleaned
'Name: 2, Test: 52, Number: 150'
>>> pairs = [part.split(':') for part in cleaned.split(',')]
>>> pairs
[['Name', ' 2'], [' Test', ' 52'], [' Number', ' 150']]
>>> {pair[0].strip(): int(pair[1].strip()) for pair in pairs}
{'Name': 2, 'Test': 52, 'Number': 150}
```

If it's more complex, or may become more complex in the future, I would recommend a YAML or JSON5 parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

first you somehow need to convert your keys to strings (or anything other than just text). e.g. from

```
"{Name: 2, Test: 52, Number: 150}"
```

to

```
"{'Name': 2, 'Test': 52, 'Number': 150}"
```

then you can use the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'Name': 2, 'Test': 52, 'Number': 150}")
{'Name': 2, 'Test': 52, 'Number': 150}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If keys are string and values are int, You can use `regex` and replace `key` with `"key"` then use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) or `json.loads`.

```
import re
import ast
import json
a_string = "{Name: 2, Test: 52, Number: 150}"
res = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', r'"\1"', a_string)  # Name -> "Name"
ast.literal_eval(res)
json.loads(res)
# {'Name': 2, 'Test': 52, 'Number': 150}
```